# No answer with predict function on svm method

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, predict

I have a data frame that I am using for machine learning using svm with the package e1071 with R. The formula I have is :

```
fidSVM = formula(y ~ a + b + c + d)
```

that I plug into :

```
fitsvm = svm(fidSVM, data = crossdata, method="C-classification", kernel="polynomial", degree=incdegree, cost=0.5, shrinking=TRUE,
           scale=TRUE, gamma=1, coef0=0, cross = 10)
```

Then, I want to predict. To test the predict() function, I simply reuse the initial data frame:

```
predict(fitsvm, crossdata)
factor(0)
Levels: 0 1
```

The classification works pretty well (I checked that), but the predict function does not work properly. As mentioned in other posts, I was careful to use a data frame to deal with my data. I have used predict svm in the past and the predict function without problems. Does anyone have an idea on what may cause the problem here?

P.S.: I do have NaN's in my data, only factors and numerical values.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this from the scikit learn module?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that. It is from the package e1071 with R.

Comment: You probably need to include some data in your question, otherwise we wont be able to tell you what's wrong....

Comment: Ok, I found a way around my problem. I just recreate a data frame. I have no idea why it is bugging, but this is what I did:

datframe = data.frame(y=crossdata$y, a=crossdata$a, b=crossdata$b, c=crossdata$c, d=crossdata$d)

Inefficient, but finally working.